# Wildfly 10 restart issue on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am running my Wildfly 10.1.0 server on Linux OS on Amazon EC2 instance. I have written start and stop scripts for the server. Whenever I stop my server and re-start after some time I get the following exception -

> WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "rapid.ear")]) - failure description: "WFLYSRV0137: No deployment content with hash dd66eee901c4bf79dd6659873df918e1b639bc1b is available in the deployment content repository for deployment 'rapid.ear'. This is a fatal boot error. To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuration file and restart."

When I remove the entry for that WAR from `standalone.xml` I am able to restart the server, but I need a more permanent solution.

The start script written is -

```
nohup /data/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/jssecacerts" --server-config=standalone.xml &
```

And the stop script is -

```
sh /data/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

Comment: Could you provide more details ? Which OS  ? Are you using the same user to install, start and stop the server ? What kind of application are you using ? Does it use datasource ? jta ? etc.

Comment: OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3
Yes, we are using the same user to install and start-stop the server.
We have an enterprise web application. 
Yes, we use data sources.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be quite as efficient in terms of I/O but if you've got a standalone instance I've just taken advantage of the deployment scanner.  I have:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
    <deployment-scanner name="myapp" path="/home/wildfly/sites/www.mysite.tld" scan-interval="60000" auto-deploy-exploded="true"/>
</subsystem>
```

in my standalone-full.xml (you may or may not need the "-full" part).  I then deploy my webapp to "/home/wildfly/sites/www.mysite.tld" and can update it as needed.  The code I show only reads the directory once a minute so it isn't terrible on I/O.

Again, your deployment may be different than mine.

Comment: We use standalone.xml and ours is a simple deployment with ear in deployment folder

Comment: Could you try https://www.dropbox.com/s/ueaurw8jseyvoum/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.tar.gz?dl=0 I may have found a fix.

Comment: ehsavoie - we can't really install any file which is not on the official website. We don't have that authorization. Is there any other solution you can help us with?

Comment: @ehsavoie - Is the solution that you used in the tar file going to be part of any upcoming release

Comment: it might make it to a wildfly 10.2 and 11 if we are quick to validate or 12 if we are late. I might backport it to 11 if there is a intermediate release. I've written the fix for 11 and backported it to 10.1 which explains also the delay.